# How can I iterate through an array and skip any empty items?

Tags: c#, csv

I have taken a csv, made from an excel file, and put it into a data table. There are cells from the excel csv file that are empty and when I iterate through them, they are also iterated through. I wish to not iterate over them.

```
foreach (DataRow datarow in sorted.Rows)
{
    Boolean first = true;
    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    foreach (var item in datarow.ItemArray)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                Console.Write(",");
            Console.Write(item);
        }

        else
            break;
    }
}
```

I have tried the above and it still iterates through the empty cells.

Comment: Check if the cell is empty, if so, `continue;`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on JohnD answer, you can try this, assuming **you only want to output the fields to the Console**:

```
var text = string.Empty;
foreach (DataRow datarow in sorted.Rows)
{
    var items = datarow.ItemArray
        .Where(x => ((x != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ToString())));
    var textJoined = string.Join(",", items);
    text += textJoined + Environment.NewLine;
}
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

You may not be familiar with LINQ, so you will need the following using statement:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Again this solution assumes you only want to output the values to the console window, it does not assume you want to iterate through all the columns for a given row. If that is what you want let me know and I can make the appropriate modifications

**[edit]**
whoops just re-read your question and it appears you do want to iterate through each column, so here is a solution below:

```
var text = string.Empty;
foreach (DataRow datarow in sorted.Rows)
{
    var items = datarow.ItemArray
        .Where(x => ((x != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ToString())));
    var currentLine = string.Empty;
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        // do something with item
        // in this case append to currentLine
        currentLine += item + ",";
    }
    text += currentLine.Substring(0, currentLine.Length - 2) + Environment.NewLine;
}
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

You get the same result, you can now just do what you need for each item

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the item is really a string, check to see if `item` is null or empty using [`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
if (item != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString()))
```

Additionally, replace the [`break`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) statement with a [`continue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx)

Comment: `item.ToString()` throws a NullReferenceException if item is null

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (DataRow datarow in sorted.Rows)
{
     Boolean first = true;
     Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
     foreach (var item in datarow.ItemArray)
     {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((item ?? "").ToString()))
          {
               int i = 0;
               if (first)
                   first = false;
               else
                    Console.Write(",");
                   Console.Write(item);
                }
                else
                    continue;
      }
}
```

Comment: `item.ToString()` throws an NullReferenceException if it's null. You could do something like `(item ?? "").ToString()` instead

Comment: @ConradFrix Good catch!

Answer (score -1):

Why not like this?

```
// ItemArray is object[]
foreach (var item in datarow.ItemArray)
{
    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // I think you are expecting to see the comma here even the previous element is empty e.g. A,B,,D (that missing C)
        Console.Write(",");
    }
    // so here we cannot guarantee "if (item is string)"
    if (item != null)
    {
        Console.Write(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

(My habit to wrap all codes in {})

Comment: Can you explain why you -1 me? Wrong logic or others?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, you just reformatted the code.

Comment: No! The original code will never write the "," if the item is null!

Comment: Then you've misunderstood the question, the OP wanted to filter out empty items and tried the null condition but that didn't help. So, you've not answered the question and then you've regressed in functionality as now it will print even if item is null

Comment: My problem is like this: 2ndtolastitem,emptyitem                Because the last item is empty, I need the comma between the 2ndtolast and last gone. I'm guessing that skipping the empty item is what I need to do but idk

Comment: I'm missing D, not C. I'm getting A,B,C, when I want A,B,C